# How to created a nested array of objects using javascript Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object

I need to loop an AJAX response and then create an array like this:

```json
"2023-03-30": {"number": '', "url": ""},
"2023-03-30": {"number": '', "url": ""}
```

The loop looks like this:

```js
var columns = {};

for (var i=0; i < parsed_data.tasks.length; i++) {
  var mydate = parsed_data.tasks[i].date; 
  columns.push(mydate);
}

console.log(columns);
```

But this doesn't give me the required result.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your expected output

Answer (score 2):

You said you aren't getting the required response. What results are you actually getting? Maybe try something like this.

```
// Declare an empty object to store the result
var result = {};

// Loop through the AJAX response array
for (i = 0; i < parsed_data.tasks.length; i++) {

  // Extract the date, number, and url values from each object
  var mydate = parsed_data.tasks[i].date;
  var number = parsed_data.tasks[i].number;
  var url = parsed_data.tasks[i].url;

  // Check if an object with the date already exists in the result object
  if (!result[mydate]) {

    // If it doesn't exist, create a new object with the date as the key and an empty object as the value
    result[mydate] = {};

  }

  // Set the number and url values for the corresponding object in the result object
  result[mydate]["number"] = number;
  result[mydate]["url"] = url;
}

// Output the final result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need date you can use `Object.keys` like:

```js
const array = [
  {"2023-03-30": {"number": '', "url": ""}},
  {"2023-03-30": {"number": '', "url": ""}}
];
const result = array.map(el => Object.keys(el)).flat();
console.log(result);
```